# Enabled protocol to https,net.tcp using C# code

Tags: c#, iis

I want to enable protocols for application in IIS to https,net.tcp using C# code. Can anybody help me with that ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that....

Comment: How to set "Enabled protocols" to "https,net.tcp" for an application in IIS using C# code.

Comment: Inside IIS, you can configure what protocols are Enabled Protocols in the Advanced Settings... box for an individual web application or web site.  He's asking if there is a way to set those options programmatically using C#.